# how can I change the "There are no items to show in this view of the..." message using code?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm creating the list view programmatically using the following code:

```
SPView myview = list.Views.Add(name, fields, query, 10, true, false);
```

how can I change the "There are no items to show in this view of the..." message using code?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to SP 2013, common way of doing this was to use XSL template overrides. But in SP 2013, this can also be done using JSLink and CSR. Example:

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.OnPreRender = csrNoListItem;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
function csrNoListItem(ctx) {
    ctx.ListSchema.NoListItem = "Your own message";
}
```

Source: http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2015/jslink-csr-to-override-there-are-no-items-to-show-in-this-view/

**UPDATE**

`SPView` has `ViewEmpty` property. Try setting this property to your custom message.

Comment: Thank you @Nedeem, but I need to change it using code behind, because the users need to add it to different pages, and it will be difficult to them to add jslink every time they use this view, also why I need to bring the text form the server and change it on the client?

Comment: @jobin, see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried but it is not working,   SPView view = list.Views.Add(name, fields, query, 10, true, false);
                view.ViewEmpty = "There are no items";
                view.Update();

Comment: What would you change in order to get this to work for a document library?  And for a bonus, how about highlighting this text?